# Order by most number of matching fields

Tags: mysql

I'm querying a table with text fields

```
| ID | Field1  | Field2  | Field3  |
| 1  | a       | random  | random  |
| 2  | a       | b       | random  | <- second best match
| 3  | random  | b       | random  |
| 4  | a       | b       | c       | <- best match

SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (Field1 = 'a' OR Field2 = "b" OR Field3 = "c")
```

All the rows respect the conditions in the WHERE, but I need to order the result so that it take in consideration the number of matching fields so that returns

```
4, 2, 1, 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9361/7

```
SELECT t.*, 
  IF(Field1 = 'a',1,0) aFlag, 
  IF(Field2 = "b",1,0) bFlag, 
  IF(Field3 = "c",1,0) cFlag
FROM table1 t
WHERE (Field1 = 'a' OR Field2 = "b" OR Field3 = "c")
ORDER BY (aFlag+bFlag+cFlag) DESC
```

**UPDATE** According to the @Neal comment that could be useful:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table1 t
WHERE (Field1 = 'a' OR Field2 = "b" OR Field3 = "c")
ORDER BY (IF(Field1 = 'a',1,0) +
  IF(Field2 = "b",1,0) + 
  IF(Field3 = "c",1,0) ) DESC
```

Comment: Can you do the IF's in the order by as well?

Comment: This is a clever solution.

Comment: @Neal I don't understand what are you asking for? Could you explain please your issue?

Comment: Ha I have no issue :-) This is not my OP. I am just asking if it is possible to have the if statements in the ORDER BY clause

Comment: @Alex It can be further simplified by removing the `if` function altogether.

Comment: @jpw how would you do that?

Comment: @Neal See my answer :) On a side note, the OP is using `"` where it should be `'` in the where clause.

Comment: @jpw Yes, I agree with you. But it is my habbits and rules to code. I would prefer to keep my first query, where I create each Flag and use IF. Additional flags help to debug and track results. And IF statement assure us that we have NUMBER value there but not mutable *boolean*

Comment: @Alex Fair enough :) Skipping `if` and evaluating the expression directly can give incorrect results if the field can be null.

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, (if(Field1 = 'a', 1, 0) + if(Field2 = "b", 1, 0) + if(Field3 = "c", 1, 0)) c 
    from table 
    order by c desc
```

Answer (score 2):

As MySQL evaluates boolean expressions as 1 or 0 the clever [solution by Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32250550/1175077) can be further reduced to this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE (Field1 = 'a' OR Field2 = 'b' OR Field3 = 'c')
ORDER BY ((Field1 = 'a') + (Field2 = 'b') + (Field3 = 'c')) DESC
```

Note that this depends on the field in the expression not being null. If it can be null then using either `IF(Field1 = 'a',1,0)` or `(coalesce(Field1,0) = 'a')` is needed to get the right results.